# Editing default Scala test template

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Is there a way to edit the template for scala test that is used by the 'create new test' action?

I tried intentions and code templates but nothing seem to expose the default template.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible. I've created a new ticket for the feature (make sure to vote for it) - https://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/SCL-10804